# Getting error 'CS0123' assigning a function to an event despite method signature matching exactly to the delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates, discord.net

Working with discord.net, I have written the following code for testing purposes:

```
// Function I want to assign to the event
private static Task MessageRecieved(SocketMessage s, Task t)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

static private DiscordSocketClient _client;

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // skip initialization stuff

    _client.MessageReceived += MessageRecieved;

    // main loop goes here
}
```

However, the line `_client.MessageReceived += MessageRecieved;` gives me this error:

> CS0123 - No overload for 'MessageRecieved' matches delegate 'Func(SocketMessage, Task)'

(The parenthesis are angle brackets, just StackOverflow formatting can't show it.)
Despite the fact that the method signature of MessageRecieved matches exactly those types, and has a return value. I have also made sure that it is not referring to some other function. Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: I believe you should not expect a task to passed in as a parameter. Generally the last type described in a delegate is the return type. Remove the task as an input param and it should work

Comment: no one ever reads exception messages :( your `MessageRecieved` is of type `Func<SocketMessage, Task, Task>`

Comment: seems to have been the issue, i didn't realize that the syntax for the delegates has the return type at the end. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for this event handler](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_BaseSocketClient_MessageReceived) states:

> The event handler must return a Task and accept a SocketMessage as its parameter.

So try removing the `Task t` parameter that you currently have and it should work:

```
private static Task MessageRecieved(SocketMessage s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer to the right docs page, i couldnt find it. the sample code they have is misleading, thanks for clearing it up